# Why does my reputation not add up?

Tags: support, bug

I recently posted a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/274208/why-does-superman-wear-a-cape-in-universe) and it was received quite positively. But I check my stack account once everyday and today when I saw my reputation timeline of upvotes I saw this -

[image]

Thats (250+70+20) - 6 which is equal to +334, but in the total rep of the day it shows +124.

This has actually happened with me quite a few times , is this a glitch??

Comment: That's weird. I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf5wm.png), so it must be something going wrong only in your personal view of the reputation page. You haven't even had 25 upvotes on that question yet, so where is the 250 coming from?!

Comment: I can confirm that I see what Rand can see as well. It's either some weird bug or shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: Not to mention you can't get 250 points in upvotes (much less 340) on any combination of posts in 1 day.

Comment: What does your reputation say now when you look at the same page?

Comment: Could be a double-counting daylight savings time bug? Was your device set to a timezone where clocks changed on Friday 24th? Or did you change timezones during this period?

Comment: @Valorum, the reputation for that day now adds up , its +130 and - 6 both for the above mentioned question

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8, I am not sure what you are saying but I have not changed any settings recently in the past months

Comment: @shanu - Almost certainly then it was a simple caching problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, this is a bug that has been [reported on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377620/ghost-nonexistent-votes-in-reputation-tab).  There are [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378170/reputation-gain-history-incorrect) [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385531/reputation-gain-from-the-last-answer-displays-the-daily-reputation) [reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378391/why-was-this-upvote-marked-as-50-in-the-profile-page) [occurrences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378469/incorrect-stats-sometimes-showing-up-is-this-a-bug) that are all marked as duplicates of the first one, but there is no actual (official) acknowledgement of the bug, nor an explanation for it.

It happened to me too today, with one answer reporting +570 in upvotes, and the total reported summing to +980 (but of course it wasn't).